# Origin of »selbstredend«

Tags: etymology, history

A little background, even though I'm native german, I'm not too certain about why we (germans) say "selbstredend" which can translate to "of course"

It's composed of

**selbst** which means self, themselves, yourself and [more](https://www.dict.cc/?s=selbst)

and

**redend** which means speaking, talking

**Example sentence:**

> Kannst du mir aus der Küche einen Apfel mitbringen? - Selbstredend!

**which translates to**

> Could you bring me an apple from the kitchen, please? - Of course!

What I don't really get is who is speaking to himself or itself?

I'm interested in how such sayings evolve :D And am happy about any hint as I couldn't find any help so far, searching in german and english.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Du kannst hier auch sehr gerne auf Deutsch fragen.

Comment: Es scheint mir in deinem Beispiel einfach falscher Sprachgebrauch zu sein. *Selbstredend* kann man nur da einsetzen, wo *Das spricht für sich selbst.* auch passen würde.

Comment: @CarstenS interessant, gut zu wissen, ich dachte es wäre nett für die Allgemeinheit und eventuell Sprachlernlinge ;-)

Comment: @Janka Aaha! Das klingt durchaus nach einem validen Punkt :D
wobei dann die ganzen englischen Übersetzungen irreführend sind, wenn selbstredend z.B. mit "of course" übersetzt wird..deine Antwort ist bisher am befriedigendsten für mich :D

Comment: @Janka mir ist natürlich schon klar, dass Wörterbücher etwas schwierig sind und nicht unbedingt immer als source of truth dienen, da oft der Kontext fehlt und es erst mal nur eine einseitige Übersetzung ist

Comment: @Janka Ich glaube nicht. "Kann ihre Maschine auch automatisch den Kaffee kochen" - "Selbstredend kann sie das". *Selbstredend* heißt einfach nur *natürlich, selbstverständlich*, auch wenn es als Wort sehr ungebräuchlich ist.

Comment: Oder - um das Wort in einen passenderen zeitlichen Kontext einzusortieren - "Dieser Unhold hat meine Schwester beleidigt. Selbstredend werde ich Satisfaktion fordern". Hier "spricht nichts für sich selbst", trotzdem passt *selbstredend* sehr gut. Das Wort ist einfach so altertümlich, dass es uns bei der trivialen Geschichte mit dem Apfel sauer aufstößt.

Comment: Für zukünftige Fragen bitte beachten: [In welcher Sprache soll man Fragen stellen?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487) Bis auf sehr wenige Ausnahmen werden hier alle Fragen von Menschen mit der Muttersprache Deutsch beantwortet.

Comment: danke für die Umformatierung @HubertSchölnast, habe mir eben auch den Link durchgelesen, vielen Dank, ich hatte bisher nur einige Fragen gelesen die in Englisch geschrieben wurden, wahrscheinlich weil die Fragenden nicht ausreichend Deutsch sprechen, daher ging ich davon aus, dass Fragen so weit möglich englisch gehalten werden ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mit *»selbstredend«* ist ursprünglich gemeint: »*diese Tatsache spricht ohnehin für sich, da muss man nicht mehr extra etwas erklären«*. Die Tatsache redet also für sich selbst. Das Wort *»selbstredend«* ist also ein Synonym für *»klar/klarerweise«*. Manche ersetzen es auch durch *»logisch/logischerweise«*.

Zwei Beispiele aus dem Internet:

> Konstruktive und faire Mitarbeiterbeziehungen sind **selbstredend** auch für die Nahrungsmittelindustrie wichtig.

Das bedeutet:
*Es ist ganz und gar offensichtlich, und müsste eigentlich überhaupt nicht gesondert erwähnt werden, weil es ohnehin jedem Menschen von selbst einleuchten muss, dass konstruktive und faire Mitarbeiterbeziehungen auch für die Nahrungsmittelindustrie wichtig sind.*

> Es ist **selbstredend**, dass kleinere Teilchen besser dispergiert und in Suspension gehalten werden können als größere.

*Es ist ganz und gar offensichtlich, und müsste eigentlich überhaupt nicht gesondert erwähnt werden, weil es ohnehin jedem Menschen von selbst einleuchten muss, dass kleinere Teilchen besser dispergiert und in Suspension gehalten werden können als größere.*

Als Antwort auf eine Bitte will man mit *»selbstredend«* ausdrücken, dass man es als selbstverständlich erachtet, die Bitte zu erfüllen.

> F: Kannst du mir aus der Küche einen Apfel mitbringen?
>
> A: Es ist ganz und gar offensichtlich, und müsste eigentlich überhaupt nicht gesondert erwähnt werden, weil es ohnehin jedem Menschen von selbst einleuchten muss, dass ich das tun werde.

Comment: Ja das klingt sehr einleuchtend, gleichzeitig ist mir dein letztes Beispiel immer noch etwas unklar. Der Apfel kann ja, in der Regel, erst mitgebracht werden, nachdem die Frage gestellt wurde. Und auf die Frage eine Antwort zu bekommen ist natürlich nett, ein "Okay", oder "Gerne" wäre auch gegangen. Bei den ersten beiden Beispielen hätte der Satz eigentlich weggelassen werden können, er ist ja "selbstredend", man fügt ihn meines Verständnisses ein um keine Zweifel offen zu lassen.
Soll ich meine Frage um dieses Kommentar ergänzen?

Comment: @Can: Du darfst Sprache, wenn es um Logik geht, nicht mit denselben Maßstäben messen wie Mathematik. Sprache ist bisweilen recht unlogisch. Tatsächlich halte ich das Wort »selbstredend« als Antwort auf eine Bitte für fehl am Platz. Aber einigen Leuten gefällt das eben, auch wenn das Wort nicht ganz passend ist. Aber du wolltest ja wissen, woher dieses Wort kommt, und nicht, ob das guter Stil ist (was meiner Meinung nach nicht der Fall ist).

Comment: Gut gesagt..am liebsten würde ich dein Kommentar als Antwort markieren ;-)